# Custom drilldown

Tags: olap, intersystems-cache, intersystems

Good evening.
Please tell me how to write a custom drilldown.
There are city (City), every city has the number of births (Amount) for each day (for example: in the last month), the values ​​of today there is empty

Here is an example of MDX query to the summary table:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY {[MEASURES]. [NEW_MEMBERMEASURE1], NONEMPTYCROSSJOIN ([Week]. [H1]. [Week]. & [NOW], [Measures]. [Amount])} ON 0, NON EMPTY [DayName]. [ H1]. [DayName] .Members ON 1 FROM [HISTORYBORN]
```

The names of the rows are the days of the week (Monday, Tuesday ... Sunday)
The first column with values ​​- the average number of births in all cities on a certain day of the week
The second column with values ​​- the total number of births in all cities in the days of the week (ie. If today is Wednesday, the value of all days except Monday and Tuesday will be empty)

Question:
What I have to write in the "Drilldown Expression" in the "Axis Options" to a double click, for example on Tuesday,and it will display a list of cities and the number of births at Tuesday !**of this week**! without columns with average values ​​(first column) and of the city, in which this day has 0 born children.

The names of the city in the next level
[City]. [H1]. [Name]

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your quetsion is not very clear but I hope it concerns custom drilldown concept in DeepSee.
You can manage custom drilldown behaviour via pivot setting in Analyzer.
As I see you have at least two separate dimensions in your cube:
Week and City.
Suppose you want to see data in weeks and then to go into cities of a particular week.
To make it do following:
Create new pivot.
Drop Week level on the Rows section
Click on the settings button of Rows 
Add custom drilldown expression with following line:
[City].[H1].[Name].Members

Enjoy your custom drilldown with cities after weeks.

Please see this [chapter](http://docs.intersystems.com/enscomm20152/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=D2ANLY_ch_custom#D2ANLY_custom_drilldown) in documentation for details.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but main problem is what i have to write to get cities with non empty count of chosen day of this week and that after double click on(for example) tuesday column with average count will "dissapear"

Comment: Another set of columns is not possible option for custom drilldown

Comment: Thanks, this's what I realy asked for

Answer (score 0):

Use [drillthrough](http://docs.intersystems.com/enscomm20152/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=D2MODEL_ch_listing#D2MODEL_listing_custom) with custom SQL listing.